# I need to send Excel file via email (not saving file on pc)

Tags: c#, email-attachments

`           Here is my workbook I created. If I save this file on hard disc, all is working okey. But looks like XLWorkbook doesnt support .xls (I got an exception). But with xlsx all is okey.

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestWorksheet");
var currentRow = 1;

worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "Test Name";
worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = "Test 1";
worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 3).Value = "Test 2";
worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 4).Value = "Test 3";
worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 5).Value = "Test 4";

//workbook.SaveAs(path + "newFile.xlsx");
```

Then am trying to send it via email.

```
try
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    Console.WriteLine(ms.Length);
    workbook.SaveAs(ms);

    Console.WriteLine(ms.Length);

    MailAddress from = new MailAddress(emailfFrom, "Me");

    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailTo);

    MailMessage m = new MailMessage(from, to);

    m.Subject = "Test";
    m.Body = "<h2>Some text here</h2>";
    m.IsBodyHtml = true;

    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, "file.xlsx", "application/excel");
    m.Attachments.Add(attach);
             
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailfFrom, password);
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(m);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

When I check the email - I got the message and the file. But When I load the file that I got by email, and try to open it I have an error that the file type was wrong or file was destroyed. And it is empty inside and no worksheet that I created.

And also when I loaded this file it was without extention. I added extention .xlsl by hands but it didnt help.

Please help. This is something with memory stream or with Content type of attachment? I tried different ("application/excel", etc.).

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, but I'll try and help.  **xls** and **xlsx** are file formats they won't affect the VBA Object Model... *I got an exception* that's not helpful, there's multiple prompts when asking a question telling you to include the error message. What documentation are you following that shows attaching an Excel file this way & what do you mean it won't save??

Comment: @JeremyThompson
Thank you for response. Sorry, am writing here for the first time.

When I tried to save file in .xls I got this exception:
**System.ArgumentException: Extention .xls is not supported. Supported extentions are .xlsx, .xlsm, .xltx, .xltm**

About documantation, I tried to find but the only think I found is that to send file by email (if it is not on a hard disc), we can use Memory Stream. And in XLWorkbook library that I use, there is method ** workbook.SaveAs(ms);** that saves file to Memory stream.

Comment: You've said you can overcome the exception saving as XSLX, so save it to disk and attach it from hard drive to the email.

Comment: @JeremyThompson The problem is that I need to do this action not on my local PC, but on production. So there is no way to save file there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the position of the memory stream after writing to it so that the stream is read from the beginning when sending the e-mail.

I.e. add this line just after `workbook.SaveAs(ms);` and it will work as expected:

```cs
workbook.SaveAs(ms);
ms.Position = 0;
```